# Bootstrap CSS library won't load

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Playing around with a tutorial that includes an intro to Bootstrap, and it shows me how to take the link from the website and add it to the file, but then the below code (div in body) won't show up as it's supposed to. Any idea why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, world!
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            A simple success alert—check it out!
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 4.5.3 was published literally 6 hours ago, the CDN hasn't been updated yet. Use 4.5.2 for now (https://www.bootstrapcdn.com for instructions.)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello!</title>
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, world!
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            A simple success alert—check it out!
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I advise you to use this bootstrap-boilerplate

```
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Bootstrap-boilerplate</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>


   <body>
<!-- Optional JavaScript-->
<!-- JQuery first, then Popper.js  the Bootstrap JS-->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice one thanks! Can you briefly explain why the need to add that?

Comment: @gds2080 this is the beta version, not a good link don't use it .. check here: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ for last version

Answer (score -4):

u should change ur link for this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: This is a bit vague.  Can you be more specific? That is the best way to help an OP get a solid path forward.